# PostgreSQL Time as PrimaryKey, don't allow Insert of entry with a Timestamp which is after the current time

Tags: postgresql, time-series

I have a Table which has a Column with timestamptz as PK and a column to store values.
The timestamptz is provided on the insert.
I do not want to allow Inserts into this table with a timestamptz which lies in the future.
The result should be an exception.

I guess i need a Rule or a Trigger function. But i do not know the best way to do this.

Example in Picture

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a check constraint because NOW() is a non deterministic function.

You can use a trigger. I used as table name mytable. Adjust the script:

```
create function check_time() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.time > now() THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'time cannot be in future';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_check_future BEFORE
INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON
    public.mytable FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION check_time();
```